# How do I divide a density/frequency plot?

Tags: clustering, histogram, clinical-trials, medicine

I have a frequency plot, which is essentially a smooth histogram. There are three very clear features (divided with a line by eye). Please note, there are two groups, male and female. The data used to generate this plot looks like:

```
  patid firstEvent  lastEvent duration Gender
1  1156 2007-08-15 2008-02-04      814   Male
2  1194 2009-03-06 2012-09-04      312   Male
3  1299 2001-11-22 2001-11-26     3331   Male
4  1445 2005-09-27 2005-09-27        1   Male
5  1476 2002-02-08 2002-02-08        1   Male
6  2045 2002-07-05 2013-07-18     3365   Male
....
```

The column *duration* is what makes up the plot.

I would appreciate suggestions for a technique that helps delimit the three features to the plot (similar to how I have done it by eye), a thus yield a list of duration cuts off which I can then use to retrieve the *patid* from the dataframe.

[image]

Comment: I would try a hierarchical clustering or linear discriminant analysis. They should pick up the groups you’ve delineated here. You might consider the log of the count variable since you have so much point mass at the low values.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into both. 
In terms of LDA, I'm not sure what my categorical variable ought to be. It can't be gender, that was just used at there are two populations in the one data.frame to be plotted in R.

Comment: Sorry! Just realised, I should manually bin and use Duration ~ patient_count as my formula.